# get key and value from hashmap in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I have a hashmap as `HashMap<String, Object>`
How can I get `key` and some Bean `variable` from the `object` value in the JSP form?

```
HashMap<String, Object> labelList = populateFieldLabels(users);
model.addAttribute("labelList", labelList);
```

I have already tried this:

```
<c:out value="${labelList.key}"></c:out>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate maps like this

```
<c:forEach items="${labelList}" var="label">
    <c:out value="${label.key}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate through map,

```
<c:forEach items="${labelList}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.key}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```